# Using a var in this Angular Directive to setValidity

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I cannot figure out how to use a variable for the following case.
In html I have the following in a loop:

```
<span ng-show='myForm." + ids[i] + ".$error.missingInfo'>Wrong!</span>";
```

The generated html is correct, meaning ids[i] makes the appropriate html, like this:

```
<span ng-show='myForm.foo.$error.missingInfo'>Wrong!</span>";
```

I have an input element that has uses a custom validation directive:

```
<input name="me-foo" id="foo-me" validateI />
```

In the directive, I want to set the validity of "myForm.foo.$error.missingInfo", so my directive:

```
app.directive('validateI', function(){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var id= attr.id;
            var x= id.indexOf("-");
            //theId will be 'foo'
            var theId= id.substring(x+1);
            if(viewValue.length > 0) {
                //this does not work
                scope.myForm.theId.$setValidity("missingInfo", true);
                //as a test, I hard-coded this and it worked:
                scope.myForm.foo.$setValidity("missingInfo", true);
             }
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("*** summary is empty");
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Is there a way to use a variable in this case, or how else would I get the 'foo' error message when the element tied to this directive is not named 'foo'?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the following to make it work:

ctrl.$setValidity("missingInfo", true);

Comment: that doesn't work, 'ctrl' is tied to the name of the element that the directive is on

Comment: What is myForm.foo? Is that actual field on the page?

Comment: yes, look at my "span" element in my question, it is part of "ng-show"..the trick is to control an error message that has a different name from the element tied to the validation directive

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using dot notation, use this notation:

```
scope.myForm[id].$setValidity("missingInfo", false);
```